# I am not sure how to place the output on separate lines

Tags: java

I am trying to append the doubles `'sum'` and `'product'` to the text area, `txaOuput`, but I don't know how to. When I click the Process button sum and double are outputted next to each other with no spaces. I just want them to be displayed line after line. Am I appending wrong?

```
private void btnProcessActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(txfNum1.getText());
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(txfNum2.getText());

    double sum = num1+num2;
    double product = num1*num2;

    txaOutput.append(String.valueOf(sum));
    txaOutput.append(String.valueOf(product));

}
```

Comment: why dont you use `txaOutput.append(String.valueOf(sum)) + "\n"` ? Its not working ?

Comment: Sorry, no, I've just tried this and it doesn't work. @Rehman

Comment: @TAsk Yep. misplaced the parenthesis. it should be `txaOutput.append(String.valueOf(sum) + "\n"`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to append a new line char at the end of each entry. If you are on windows you can use `\r\n` else use just `\n`.

```
txaOutput.append(String.valueOf(sum));
txaOutput.append("\r\n")
txaOutput.append(String.valueOf(product));
```